# Npm redis client cannot get key when doing a GET request on an express route in a Node.js application

Tags: node.js, docker, express, npm, redis

##### Short

Redis is `OK` but I cannot get in the redis `client.get()` function in a Node.js app.

##### Details

I have this small NodeJS `server.js` file:

```js
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const redis = require('redis');
const PORT = 80;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';
const app = express();

const client = redis.createClient({
  url: 'redis://redis:6379'
});

(async () => {
  await client.connect();
})();

client.on('connect', () => console.log('->Redis Client Connected!'));
client.on('error', (err) => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello world'); // <-- works perfectly
});

app.get('/foo', (req, res) => {
  console.log("in /foo"); // <--------------------- this prints correctly 
  client.get('numVisits', (err, numVisits) => {
    console.log("in client.get()"); // <----------- this never prints to stdout
    let numVisitsToDisplay = parseInt(numVisits, 10) + 1;
    if (isNaN(numVisitsToDisplay)) {
      numVisitsToDisplay = 1;
    }
    res.send(`<h1>Number of visits is: ${numVisitsToDisplay}`);
    numVisits++;
    client.set('numVisits', numVisits);
  });
});

app.listen(PORT, HOST, () => {
  console.log(`Web app running on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
});
```

inspired from: https://dev.to/docker/dockerizing-a-nodejs-express-redis-app-with-nginx-proxy-using-docker-compose-17ge

but this requests hang on for ever :

```
$ curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost/foo
```

Same in my web browsers.

The `redis-cli monitor` shows this same line line each time a send a GET request:

```
OK
1680371594.117283 [0 172.19.0.3:56048] "GET" "numVisits"
1680371617.701439 [0 172.19.0.3:56048] "GET" "numVisits"
```

and the log of the Node.js server is as follow, the last line also repeats on each GET request:

```
Web app running on http://0.0.0.0:80
-> Redis Client Connected!
in /foo
in /foo
```

Here's my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "web_app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My first Node.js app",
  "author": "myself",
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "pg": "^8.10.0",
    "redis": "^4.6.5"
  }
}
```

How could I get `redis` to work properly for storing the number of hits when doing GET requests to the route `/foo`?

Both redis and the node web app work as docker containers on the same network in a very basic compose file:

```
volumes:
  redis:

services:
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
    - redis:/var/lib/redis

  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - redis
```

Node version is: `v17.6.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue's actually with using callbacks not Promises for the `get`.  This changed in Node-Redis 4.  You can also simplify your code to use just the Redis `INCR` command that assumes a keys's value is 0 if not set, then adds 1 to it and treats it as a number (see https://redis.io/commands/incr/).

This example should do what you want with less code - I've changed the Redis hostname to `localhost` to test in my environment:

```js
const express = require('express');
const redis = require('redis');
const PORT = 8000;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';
const app = express();

const client = redis.createClient({
  url: 'redis://localhost:6379'
});

(async () => {
  await client.connect();
})();

client.on('connect', () => console.log('->Redis Client Connected!'));
client.on('error', (err) => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));

app.get('/foo', async (req, res) => {
  console.log("in /foo"); 
  const numVisits = await client.incr('numVisits');
  res.send(`<h1>Number of visits is: ${numVisits}</h1>`);
});

app.listen(PORT, HOST, () => {
  console.log(`Web app running on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
});
```

Here's the `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "nrexpress",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "redis": "^4.6.5"
  }
}
```

If you want to use a module and simplify a little more, add `"type": "module"` to `package.json` and rewrite `server.js` like this:

```js
import express from 'express';
import { createClient } from 'redis';
const PORT = 8000;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';
const app = express();

const client = createClient({
  url: 'redis://localhost:6379'
});

client.on('connect', () => console.log('->Redis Client Connected!'));
client.on('error', (err) => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));
await client.connect();

app.get('/foo', async (req, res) => {
  console.log("in /foo"); 
  const numVisits = await client.incr('numVisits');
  res.send(`<h1>Number of visits is: ${numVisits}</h1>`);
});

app.listen(PORT, HOST, () => {
  console.log(`Web app running on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
});
```

This allows you to use top level `await`.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks a lot. BTW I had other packages, e.g. `pg` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg) or surprisingly even `express` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) which doesn't have an ES6 enabled documentation on the npm website but I was finally able to migrate all my imports to the ES6 notation, which is a good thing! Also now it's clearer why on the redis npm webpage one can find `await` statements floating outside any `async` scope! It was super strange to me! Finally, do you know a way to get the `redis-cli monitor` to actually also print the number of hits?